# How to add Icons in Django forms

Tags: django, font-awesome

So I wanted to add icons of font-awesome inside the input boxes which are rendered by django, but found no way to do so. The input boxes are provided by the django via

```
{{form.username}}
```

type of fields, and the output is like

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" required placeholder="Username" maxlength="32" />
```

I achieved placeholder via the django widgets such as

```
username = forms.CharField(
        required = True,
        label = 'Username',
        max_length = 32,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder':'Username'},
            ),
        )
```

I would like to know how to place icons there too just like the image [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Fy5.png)
 who's code is shown here

```
<input placeholder="First Name" name="Name" class="name" type="text" required="">
<span class="icon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the class "icon1" will have some css because your example code will not be the same as on the picture. Get the rest of the css/ html and reproduce it. next to your `{{form.username}}` put the `<span class="icon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria ...` and you will be fine

Comment: @hansTheFranz this is putting the icon at the end of the input box

Comment: please educate yourself about what django is used for. django is not a front-end library for styling forms. Django provides you this form field with its template language but you dont have to use it. you can wirte custom HTML and it will work as well but your problem stays the same. Enter your example code you wrote here in JS fiddle and you will relaise its and css/html problem and has nothing to do with django

Answer (score 1):

In your template do this

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}" id="group_{{ field.name }}">
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This should help you solve your problem!

Comment: This will put the icon outside the input box. What is required over here is that the icon to be inside the input box.

Comment: for bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/
Otherwise, you will have to do some workaround with CSS to make it work
as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/y6xtuj4c/1/

Comment: the problem here isn't bootstrap or CSS, I believe the problem here is the django

Comment: Of course, Django is backend framework. It has limitations to frontend customizations.

Comment: your solution adds the same user icon to every field in the for loop, so not very practical answer

Answer (score 1):

custom ModelForm class
adds form-control class to all fields and looks for icons defined

```py
class BootstrapModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        icons = getattr(self.Meta, 'icons', dict())

        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            # add form-control class to all fields
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            # set icon attr on field object
            if field_name in icons:
                field.icon = icons[field_name]
```

then add icons dict in your Meta class
this works the same as you would define `labels` or `widgets`

```py
class UserForm(BootstrapModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',]
        icons = {'username': 'user-circle'}
```

now in html template use the icon attr on the field
this example assumes font-awesome library of icons

```html
</form>
  {% for form_field in form %}
    <div class="input-group">
      <span>

        <i class="fas fa-{{ form_field.field.icon }}"></i>

      </span>
      {{ form_field }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

use css to place icon over the input (if your really feel you need to)

```css
span{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
input{
  padding-left: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using material-icon, you need to install it first

```
pip install django-material
```

```html
            {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
            <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method='post'>
                <h3 class='center orange-text'>Log In Form</h3>
                {%csrf_token%}
                {% form %}
                {% part form.user_name prefix %}<i class='material-icons prefix orange lighten-4'>account_box</i>{% endpart%}
                {% part form.password prefix %}<i class='material-icons prefix or lighten-4'>lock_open</i>{% endpart %}
                {% endform%}
                <button required type="button" name="button" class='btn-large orange black-text right'  >Log In</button>
            </form>
```

Include the following in base html or in the html you are currently working on

```
{% include 'material/includes/material_css.html' %}
{% include 'material/includes/material_js.html' %}
```

Comment: {% include 'material/includes/material_css.html' %}
{% include 'material/includes/material_js.html' %}   are mandatory

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this, although it might require some more work to position the icon on the screen, depending of what you want.

Template.html

```html
<div class="col">
  {{form.your_field_here.label_tag}} 
  <i title="{{ form.your_field_here.help_text }}" class="fas fa-question">
    {{ form.your_field_here }}
  </i>
</div>
```

View.py

```py
your_field_here = forms.CharField(
    label='Your field label here',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'}),
    help_text='Your help text to appear in the tooltip')
```